# How are bug/performance fixes in the ExcelApi deployed for the desktop versions of Office, and JavaScript files required for web Excel Add-ins

Tags: office-js

For example if a bug fix is made to the property ‘Range.values’ or method ‘TableRowCollection.add’, which are both in ExcelApi 1.1, how and when would fix be made available.

Desktop versions of Office:
Would it only be made available in the next version of the API (ExcelApi 1.9), and so only available in the next msi release of Office (2020/21), and would support for ExcelApi 1.9 be added to office 2016 or 2019 as part of a service pack update to these products?
Would it be made available as an update to the existing versions of the API (ExcelApi 1.1), would this deployed as a MS update or service pack update to products that support this version of the API (office 2016 and 2019)?

JavaScript files required for web Excel Add-ins:
How are the latest versions of the Office JavaScript files made available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest versions of the Office JavaScript library are made available on the CDN and also as an npm package. For details, see [Referencing the JavaScript API for Office library from its content delivery network (CDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/referencing-the-javascript-api-for-office-library-from-its-cdn).

A bug fix for ExcelApi 1.1 that requires only changes in the JavaScript, not in the underlying Office host application, would be included in the next update of the CDN. Fixes that change the underlying code would be made available to the subscription based Office as part of the next update. If the bug fix is serious enough, it might be backported to the perpetual (MSI) versions of Office as an update.

New versions of ExcelApi, such as 1.9, are *not* added to the perpetual (MSI) editions of Office.

BTW, Microsoft is not committed to providing another perpetual (MSI) version of Office after Office 2019.